# Thymeleaf attributes with no html element

Tags: java, thymeleaf

What I do is use the Thymeleaf attributes but I don't want to have for example an extra div.

For example, I have this

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    This content is only shown to administrators. 
</div>
```

But I'd like something like this:

```
<sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    This content is only shown to administrators. 
</>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What you have posted is not valid xml/html. Thymeleaf expects valid html (tags) with custom attributes that it can use to render a view.

Comment: Hi Sotirios, I know that is not valid, is an example of what I need. Do you know how to handle this?

Comment: What I was trying to say is, since HTML doesn't have such tags and Thymeleaf uses HTML tags to render templates, you won't be able to achieve what you want with Thymeleaf. Not as far as I know.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [th:block](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#synthetic-thblock-tag) tag:

```
<th:block sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    This content is only shown to administrators. 
</th:block>
```

From the Thymeleaf docs:

> th:block is a mere attribute container that allows template developers to specify whichever attributes they want. Thymeleaf will execute these attributes and then simply make the block dissapear without a trace.